# Error when trying to convert .doc to .pdf with Python

Tags: python, pdf, doc

I've been trying to convert old .doc files to PDFs using Python, but I have been running into some trouble. Here is my code:

```
import os 
import comtypes.client 

format_code = 17
file_input = os.path.abspath('(1)2014-06-18.doc')
file_output = os.path.abspath('test.pdf')

word_app = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
word_file = word_app.Documents.Open(file_input)
word_file.SaveAs(file_output,FileFormat=format_code)
word_file.Close()
word_app.Quit()
```

Whenever I execute it, I get:

```
Users/gawel/OneDrive/Desktop/scraping/doctotxt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/gawel/OneDrive/Desktop/scraping/doctotxt.py", line 10, in <module>
    word_file.SaveAs(file_output,FileFormat=format_code)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

I have been trying to do some research on what this error could be mean, but I have been unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know the library you’re using but have you tried writing output (pdf data) to a file manually using Python’s built-in file I/O operations?

Comment: @YılmazAlpaslan I also looked into doing this, but the solutions I found only worked for .docx files, not .doc files like I want

Comment: @KJ I'm not sure what you mean to be honest, I thought the format code had to be a number

Comment: @KJ I tried both, and I still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
# Open Microsoft DOC 

app = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
  
# Read Doc File
doc = app.Documents.Open('C:/Users/<User>/Downloads/document.docx')
  
# Convert into PDF File
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat('C:/Users/<User>/Downloads/document.pdf', 17, Item=7, CreateBookmarks=0)
app.Quit()
```

If it still doesn't work, try deleting the cache files inside the "gen" folder in the path:

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen

Try using the msoffice2pdf library using Microsoft Office or LibreOffice installed in the environment.

https://pypi.org/project/msoffice2pdf/